# MOXy @XmlPath expressions, are they supported?

Tags: java, xml, xpath, moxy

Are XPath expressions such as the following supported in MOXy?

```
field[XMLtag!='identifier']
```

Basically I've got XML like this

```
<demographics>
  <field>
    <value>12345</value>
    <XMLtag>identifier</XMLtag>
  </field>
  <field>
    <value>somename</value>
    <XMLtag>name</XMLtag>
  </field>
</demographics>
```

I'm trying to get a List to populate with but exclude the field which is for identifier.

This will work but gives me all field elements (2) in the `List` ( correctly )

```
@XmlElement( name = "field" )
public List<Field2> fieldList;
```

This will not, I get an empty `List`

```
@XmlPath( "field[XMLtag!='identifier']" )
public List<Field2> fieldList;
```

Should the above work, or are expressions like that not supported by MOXy? I can't seem to find any information about them.

I've not included my Field2 class as it's very simple and obviously works okay as I can unmarshall to list if using `@XmlElement` annotation. Let me know if you'd like to see it.

Answer (score 2):

[**EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy)**](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/moxy.php)'s `@XmlPath` annotation supports a subset of the XPath specification. The XPath handling is done by MOXy itself.  The following concepts are supported:

- Attribute - `@id`
- Element - `address`
- Element by Position - `address[1]`
- Element by Predicate - `address[@type='mailing']`
- Element Text - `name/text()`
- Text - `text()`
- Self - `.`
- Combination - `personal-info/name[2]/text()`

For namespace qualified nodes, the prefixes defined in the `@XmlNs` annotations can be used to qualify the XPath fragments.  Unqualified fragments will assumed to be in the namespace specified using `@XmlSchema`.

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/09/xpath-based-mapping-geocode-example.html